# How to log errors for move_uploaded_file to a file

Tags: php, error-handling

I have some code that uploads a file, its the exact same code i had working on another server but its not working on this new server

```
// Move the file into the new folder
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],'./img/myfolder/1/'. $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

I know i can use:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],'./img/myfolder/1/'. $_FILES["file"]["name"])){
echo "success";
} else{
echo "failure";
}
```

However i have 2 problems, the script is not ran directly from the page, another application which i dont have access to source code to calls that page and sends the image. So i cant do any in page errors i need to log the errors to a file.

The 2nd problem and the main issue is i am not sure how to find out what the error is. Is there an error code i can pull if the else statement is called. I have set it to 777 for the folders and subfolders just for testing purposes to rule out permission issues, ill fix that after getting the problem resolved before pushing to production.

Also i checked the apache server error.log file and it shows nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here i would do something like this.

```
 $debug_file = _DIR_.'/debug.txt';

 $source = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
 $dest = './img/myfolder/1/'. $_FILES["file"]["name"];


if(! @move_uploaded_file($source,$dest) ){
     file_put_contents(  $debug_file, "ERROR[ ".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')." ] Could not move[ $source ] to[ $dest ]\n", FILE_APPEND);
     exit();
}
```

Then when you have the source and dest paths you can make sure they actually exist in the right places.

-note- the @ sign will suppress the normal PHP warning for failing to move the file, but as we are logging it our self, this just prevents it from getting in the way.

Also I put an exit in, I'm assuming its a requirement of this script to have the file to work properly, and that way it's enough just to fail, no need to check for success.

Most likely, the file path is wrong

Also you could even output buffer the php error as well like this,

```
ob_start();
$moved = move_uploaded_file($source,$dest);
$message = ob_get_clean();
if(!$moved){
    file_put_contents(  $debug_file, "ERROR[ ".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')." ] Could not move[ $source ] to[ $dest ] PHP message[ $message ]", FILE_APPEND);
 exit();
}
```

Output buffing works wonders on scripts ran in the background,

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php

Comment: Yep you were spot on, i forgot that even though the script was the same this file was 1 level deeper, just needed ../img/myfolder/1/ to drop back 1 level and that worked

Comment: Yea that is usually the case, I often find just taking the actual location of images/files and comparing that to where the code thinks it is is the best way to see any differences.